# Web proxy with server-side scripts execution

Tags: html, proxy

I'm looking for something that works like transcoders of Opera Mini or UC Browser, but sends intermediate states of a page to the client in plain HTML+CSS instead of proprietary markup. Possibility of installation to an own server would be a plus. The solution must be self-sufficient, not something like toonel.net that relies on a third-party service that may eventually fail.